# How can I change center of a view, which is stored in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to access property of UIView stored in NSArray but getting "Property 'center' not found on object of type'id'" message. What can i do to avoid this?

```
[_toggles objectAtIndex:i-1].center = CGPointMake(i * (toogleSize + freeSpace) - 24, 48);
```

Comment: `UIView *v = _toggles[i-1]; v.center = CGPointMake(i* . . .`  Currently you are trying to call `center` on an object of type `id` (what `-objectAtIndex:` returns - you need to assign it to a variable of type `UIView` to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: or... `((UIView*)_toggles[i-1]).center = CGPointMake(...);`

Comment: @godel9, thank you! I tried to do the same thing, but forgot to use brackets around (UIView*)_toggles[i-1] so it didn't know what I want :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the result of `_toggles[i-1]` to a `UIView*` and then access the `center` property:

```
((UIView*)_toggles[i-1]).center = CGPointMake(...);
```

You just have to remember the parentheses in the right place to make sure you cast `_toggles[i-1]` before you access `center`.